# "GCP Storage Output between NA and APAC" cost on my billing using Google Colab and US storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-colaboratory

I have a storage located in nam4 (Iowa and South Carolina) and I'm using Google Colab and sending requests to that storage. I'm authenticating (using gcloud init) in Colab by selecting a US region. Why do I get the "GCP Storage Output between NA and APAC" cost on my billing?

Comment: This is a billing question which is off-topic here. Contact GCP billing support and they will help you with that

Comment: You colab instance should be located in APAC. Gcloud init doesn't allow you to select a region! it's only configuration in the CLI params.

Comment: This is related to billing support. Please [contact](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why. I thought all Colab servers were in the US, but checking the IP geolocation using GPU VM, I found the server was in Taiwan. When booting a VM with TPU or None, the server was in the US

I used `!curl https://ipinfo.io/ip` to check ip and https://www.ip2location.com/demo to check geolocation